# jQuery not fading text in and out?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I want to display "goodbye" for 1 second, fade it out, replace it with 
"hello", and then fade back in. Why doesn't this snippetwork? (jQuery 
is loaded):

```
<div id="foo">x</div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#foo').fadeOut().html('goodbye').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut().html('hello').fadeIn(); 
</script>
```

I'm using the queue correctly, so these commands occur in order (not asynchronously), right?

Full version: http://test.barrycarter.info/stacked1.html

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who answered! I appreciate the alternate suggestions. I guess my real question was "why doesn't my code work?" I'm learning jQuery, and figuring out where my code goes wrong would really help me!

Answer (score 2):

You want to make the `fadeIn` part of the callback function of `fadeOut`.  So...

```
$('#foo').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#foo').fadeIn('slow').html('Hello');
});
```

Change `slow` to `1000` for 1 second or whatever is desired.

http://jsfiddle.net/qK26W/

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code.just look at this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/anish/cZf6g/

Answer (score 0):

try putting your statement in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*code here*/
});
```

or putting it in a function then calling that function